# MySQL / MariaDB troubleshooting stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to write the following stored procedure but I keep getting a syntax error, which I've included under the SP.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(categoryID int, userID int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vbUserId INT DEFAULT ( SELECT userfield.field6 FROM userfield WHERE userfield.field6 = userID );
    DECLARE m_forumId, m_numOfPosts, m_numOfThreads, m_hasChildren, m_isPrivate INT;
    DECLARE m_forumName VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE lastRow INT DEFAULT 0;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp engine=memory AS (select forumid,replace(replace(title_clean,'&amp;','&'),'&quot;','') as forumName,replycount as NumOfPosts, threadcount as NumOfThreads, 0 as hasChildren, showprivate as isprivate from forum where parentid=categoryID and displayorder!=0 and options&1=1 order by displayorder);

    DECLARE cur_forums CURSOR FOR select * from tmp;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET lastRow = 1;
    OPEN cur_forums;
    iterate_forums: LOOP
        FETCH cur_forums INTO m_forumId, m_forumName, m_numOfPosts, m_numOfThreads, m_hasChildren, m_isPrivate;             
        IF lastRow = 1 THEN LEAVE iterate_forums;
        IF (m_isPrivate = 1)
            SELECT CONCAT('Private: ', m_isPrivate);
        END IF
    END LOOP iterate_forums;
    CLOSE cur_forums;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

END$$
```

Here is the error I receive when I try to import this into a db:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur_forums CURSOR FOR select * from tmp;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR N' at line 10
```

I've read the documentation and looked over previous SO questions, and also tried commenting out certain lines or running them on their own, but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chuck `tmp` and the `cursor`.  Instead, have simply

```
select "Private: 1"
    FROM forum
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
           from forum
           where parentid=categoryID
             and displayorder!=0
             and options&1=1
             AND showprivate = 1 );
```

`vbUserId` seems to be unused; get rid of it.

Comment: It's used, just not in this unfinished portion of code. :) I should have posted the whole thing because then your answer actually wouldn't fit. But since I didn't, have the points.

Answer (score 1):

change the order like: 1 declare, then open

```
....
    DECLARE vbUserId INT DEFAULT ( SELECT userfield.field6 FROM userfield WHERE userfield.field6 = userID );
    DECLARE m_forumId, m_numOfPosts, m_numOfThreads, m_hasChildren, m_isPrivate INT;
    DECLARE m_forumName VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE lastRow INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  cur_forums CURSOR FOR select * from tmp;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET lastRow = 1;

    OPEN cur_forums;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp engine=memory AS (select forumid,replace(replace(title_clean,'&amp;','&'),'&quot;','') as .....
...
```

Comment: How can I select from "tmp" table when declaring the cursor if I haven't created the table yet?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by re-writing as so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(categoryID int, userID int)
BEGIN
        DECLARE vbUserId INT DEFAULT (
               SELECT userfield.field6 FROM userfield
                   WHERE userfield.field6 = userID );
        DECLARE m_forumId, m_numOfPosts, m_numOfThreads,
                m_hasChildren, m_isPrivate INT;
        DECLARE m_forumName VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE lastRow INT DEFAULT FALSE;

        DECLARE curForums CURSOR FOR select * from tmp;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET lastRow = TRUE;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp engine=memory AS (
            select forumid,
                   replace(replace(title_clean,'&amp;','&'),'&quot;','')
                             as forumName,
                   replycount as NumOfPosts,
                   threadcount as NumOfThreads,
                   0 as hasChildren,
                   showprivate as isprivate
               from forum
               where parentid=categoryID
                 and displayorder!=0
                 and options&1=1
               order by displayorder);

        OPEN curForums;
        iterateForums: LOOP
                FETCH curForums INTO m_forumId, m_forumName,
                                     m_numOfPosts, m_numOfThreads,
                                     m_hasChildren, m_isPrivate;
                IF lastRow THEN 
                    LEAVE iterateForums;
                END IF;
                IF m_isPrivate = 1 THEN 
                    SELECT (m_isPrivate);
                END IF;                 
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE curForums;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```